# What is the significance of the name "telophase topology"?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Steen and Seebach, in their Counterexamples in Topology (2ed, 1978) define the "telophase topology" as:

"Let $(X, \tau)$ be the topological space formed by adding to the ordinary closed unit interval $[0,1]$ another right-hand end point, say $1^*$, with the sets $(a,1) \cup \{1^*\}$ as a local neighborhood basis."

What is the significance of the term "telophase", and who coined it?

My research:

According to Wikipedia, I learn that "telophase" is a term in biology for a late stage in the process of cell division, at which point all the interior components of the cell have separated into two aggregations just before the cell actually divides into two parts.

I gather that the main significance of this topology (and its *raison d'être*) is the fact that it has compact subsets $[0,1]$ and $[0,1) \cup \{1^*\}$ whose intersection is not compact, and perhaps the term "telophase" is a picturesque way of providing an analogy between two daughter cells (in the biological context) and those two "daughter" closed unit intervals which are separately compact sets which are still, so to speak, "inside" the parent cell $(X, \tau)$.

I can't find any discussion about this topology in the online literature. While S&S has a comprehensive bibliography, it does not match the citations with their appearance in the text.)

Comment: I'd split up this question and move the local base part to a separate one.

Comment: yes okay, that makes sense. thx

Comment: ... that has now been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know who came up with this name, it's just the same idea as the "line with double origin", which is a standard example to show that Hausdorff is "needed" in the definition of manifold, e.g. Maybe instead of using split point, or double point etc. they liked a "fancy" name and opted for the biological metaphor.

Comment: The line with double origin I have not encountered yet, but next on the list to analyse is the double origin plane, once I've got my head round what it says.

Comment: @PrimeMover See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold#Line_with_two_origins) for the line with two origins. It's a different animal from S&S's double origin plane. S&S use weird names for the examples sometimes.

Comment: Indeed they do. Hence my ongoing exercise to correlate and consolidate the various terminologies. It appears that nobody has done this, and schools of study seem merely to entrench their own terminology schemata without making much attempt to present lists of alternative names for the various concepts. I have to start somewhere, and S&S is as good a place as any, as a (now somewhat tattered) copy is at my elbow.

Comment: ...cont: I'm not even sure the "line with double origin" is even included in S&S, although I haven't completed my study of it yet, so it may be there somewhere but I just haven't got to yet.